# Android time lag in network response

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, android-networking

I am getting data for one single database from two different network calls. one response takes 5 seconds and another takes 15 seconds. Now, the condition is I can present data to the user only after having an entire dataset ready in my memory from both the network calls. 
So, 
1) How can I deal with this(15-5 = 10sec.) time lag?
2) I have to have shown some data to the user simultaneously. I can not leave them blank until I'll have the entire dataset ready in memory.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? What precisely are you looking help for, reducing time delays somehow or handing asynchronous responses gracefully?

Comment: @Mladen I have edited the question. please have a look.

Comment: Since this is still a too broad question, I'll try to comment out a couple of relevant principals. Check out the answer and comment out with additional questions if needed

Comment: @DharitParmar: it's weird that an API call takes 15 sec for a response. Maybe you can call the required functionality earlier and keep it ready. Even if the user does not go to that option you can download and keep it in app database and if the user goes there you can add an option to refresh the data as in meanwhile user can see the earlier data.

Answer (score 0):

From a UX perspective - you are absolutely right when saying that you should show some data to a user sooner rather than later. You should populate your result list with some data as soon as first request is loaded, and fill it up with additional ones once a second one resolves. You should for certain wanna show a loading indicator while loading is still in progress! There is a good explanation of progress indicators in [Material Design Guidelines](https://material.io/design/components/progress-indicators.html#linear-progress-indicators).

I just noticed that you tagged this question with `retrofit` and `rx-java` tags. Using those, it's easy to wait for both requests to finish and write code that will execute afterwards. You may use [zip method](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) of `RxJava`. `Zip` will take multiple [Observables](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html) and:

> "return an Observable that applies a function of your choosing to the
>   combination of items emitted, in sequence, by two (or more) other
>   Observables, with the results of this function becoming the items
>   emitted by the returned Observable."

Assuming you have two base observable objects (one for each of your two requests), on compleating each of them you fill in your data set (probably [RecyclerView's adapter??](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter)), and after both are complete (zip's observable) you hide a progress loading indicator.